# Detect substring, then remove the rest of the string after substring including substring itself in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string `Start-Substring-abcde` in python. I want to detect the presence of a substring, say `-Substring`. If this substring is detected, then the rest of the string will be removed, including the substring itself.

For example, `Start-Substring-abcde` will return `Start` after removing the relevant characters.

I am using python 3.9

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by `try except` as it is faster than `if` statement.

```
x = 'Start-Substring-abcde'
try:
    x = x[:x.index('-Substring')]
except ValueError:
    pass
```

This code removes the `substring` and the following words to the end of the string if the `substring` exists in the string. Otherwise it do nothing to the string.

If you want to do this with if statement you can do it this way:

```
x = 'Start-Substring-abcde'

if '-Substring' in x:
    x = x[:x.index('-Substring')]

print(x)
```

If you have any question feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to understand what does :x do? what's the role of : ? Any link I can read about : ?

Comment: `x.index('-Substring')` means the start index of your substring. The `:` before that says: Get every thing from the beginning of the sentence to this index. For example x[2:5] means get indexs 2,3,4 and x[:5] means get from the begining to index 5 resulting in this: 0,1,2,3,4.

Comment: Your welcome my friend. The reason that I didn't use `.split()` method is that `split` creates a whole list of all the string and even it checks the string to the last index. But in the code I provided for you, if python finds the substring it doesn't search the next chars. So this makes it faster.

Answer (score 1):

The first index of `str.split()` where you split by the substring will be the part of the initial string before the substring (if the substring does not exist in the initial string then the initial string will be returned)

```
in_str = 'Start-Substring-abcde'
sub_str = '-Substring'
result = in_str.split(sub_str)[0]
print(result) # 'Start'
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant answer. It is simple and can be understood by me.